# How Linkers Resolve Global Symbols with the same name Defined at Multiple Places

Tags: c

i am new in programming and i started with c . i am learning in the point How Linkers Resolve Global Symbols Defined at Multiple Places. so i made a small program which says:

//main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void b(void);


int x;
int a=10;
int y =500;
int x1 = 2016;

int main()
{
b();


printf("x = %1f y = %d\n",x , y);
return 0;
}
```

//second_file.c

```
double x=100.0;
int g=100;
extern int y;
void b()
{
x = -100.0;

}
```

i know from the rules that linkers follow to solve this case that, the linker will choose the strong symbol which in this case (double x=100.0;) not the integer one defined in main.c. so i expected the output to be x=-100.0 y=500,
but the output was x=0.000000 y=89 can any one explain why did i find this output or where is my wrong?

i tried to use objdump command in cmd (for windows) to view the symbol table may i find something make my understand but i found another thing weird i found the addresses of the variables as follow:

a------ 0x00000000

y------ 0x00000004

x1----- 0x00000008

x------ 0x00000010

g------ 0x00000018

i thought that x should start from 0x0000000c why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may or may not know, you need to be careful with multiple definitions.  Ideally, every global symbol will be defined precisely once.  There are various circumstances under which you can get away with multiple definitions, but you have to be careful.

In this case, you're relying on the "common allocation model", which was (and still is) widespread among C compiler because of the early influence of, believe it or not, FORTRAN.  This model says that you can have multiple definitions as long as at most one of gives an initializing value. But -- and this is the biggie -- *all the definitions must have the same type*.  (I'm not sure I've ever seen this rule stated; I'm not sure I'd even thought about it explicitly, because it ends up being pretty obvious that it has to be that way.)

C uses the concept of *separate compilation*.  Each .c file compiles down to a separate, standalone "object file".  Later, a separate program called the *linker* links the object files together.  It's the linker that assigns the final address to global variables, and ends up resolving common allocation.

But the linker only resolves addresses.  It will arrange that `x` in your `main.c` and `x` in your `second_file.c` are at the same address.  But if `main.c` thinks there's an `int` located at location `x`, that's how it's going to interpret it.  And if `second_file.c` thinks there's a `double` at location `x`, and indeed stores a value of type `double` there, it's going to be gibberish when `main.c` tries to interpret that bit pattern as an `int`.

As @user58697 discusses in another answer, you've got additional problems in your `printf` call, trying to use `%f` to print (what the compiler thinks are) `int` values, which is never going to work properly, either.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration in main.c

```
int x;
```

has nothing to do with the one in second_file.c

```
double x=100.0;
```

because their scope (visibility) is limited to its compilation unit. That is, their are globals but (roughly) only visible along functions in the same file.
In case you wanted both files to share the same global variable you have to specify it by using `extern`keyword:

```
extern int x;
```

in one of the files, and that will force the linker to match a symbol at linking time that implements that declaration.

Don't forget: you can declare a variable (consistently in type) multiple times but only define it once. To avoid taking this answer too long, try to search in stackoverflow for the best approach for using globals in multiple files; it's much better to work via *.h for declarations an of course implement it in one *.c file.

Finally, in this example anyway the linker will not match the `int x`declaration with the `double x`definition, and it will throw an error at linking time.

Comment: i know how to use extern for declaration but this is not my question my question was there are 3 rules that the linker follow during linking time when global Symbols Defined at Multiple Places 

Rule 1: Multiple strong symbols (with same variable name) are not allowed.

Rule 2: Given a strong symbol and multiple weak symbols, choose the strong 
symbol
.
Rule 3: Given multiple weak symbols, choose any of the weak symbols.

this case the linker should use rule 2 

finally the linker didn't throw an error 

 and in another program chick rule 2 it works as expected

Comment: *their scope (visibility) is limited to its compilation unit* Are you sure about that? Per [**6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**, paragraph 5 of the C Standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2p5):  "If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external."  That seems to say that if an object with file scope *doesn't* have `static`, it has an implicit `extern`.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the line

```
    printf("x = %1f y = %d\n",x , y);
```

you lied to `printf`. You told the compiler to push an `int` (apparently 4 bytes worth), but instructed `printf` to pull a `double` (apparently 8 bytes). This is an UB. All bets are off. Nobody knows where `printf` would pull `y` from.

And this is what happens with `x`:

```
vnp$ nm -n main.o
                 U _b
                 U _printf
0000000000000000 T _main
0000000000000004 C _x
0000000000000040 D _a
0000000000000044 D _y
0000000000000048 D _x1
```

You can see that `_x` is annotated with `C` (for `Common`). The compiler took `int x;` as a *definition*, realized that `x` is an uninitialized global, and placed  it in `BSS`. By the time it compiled the

```
    printf("x = %1f y = %d\n",x , y);
```

line, it generated a relocation record relative to the `.bss`.

The linker, however, selected `x` from the second file, and which is placed in `.data`, but performed the relocation as directed, that is relative to `.bss`. This is why `x` prints as `0`.

Disclaimer: since there is an UB, the above is a pure (however educated) speculation.

PS: the address of `x` is due to the alignment requirement or `double`.

Comment: thnx alot ur first paragraph was very helpful about UB i found it was the reason for the value x=0 and y=89 when i changed %1f to%d the value of y became  500 as expected but x still 0 . as @Steve Summit discussed in his pre-last paragraph i known that the problem was in the format which every data type represented by it ,in second_file.c when the compiler find -100 is given to a double type var (will b() is called)then -100 is stored in x(8 byte) in the followed formate for double but in main.c  the compiler push only 4bytes which content is 0 because -100 is a very small compared to double

Comment: i tried to give x a very high value x = -19999655455854555.0 so it give a value in the output not equal to zero and i think the function pulled the 4 bytes and treated with them as they represent an integer value.